# What is the CMB when casting Hydraulic Push from a Tidewater Cutlass as a Swashbuckler?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items

When using a [Tidewater Cutlass](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/specific-magic-weapons/tidewater-cutlass/) to cast [Hydraulic Push](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/h/hydraulic-push/), what would the CMB be?  It's normally caster level plus an attribute mod, but I'm a Swashbuckler, I don't have a caster level! I'm aware that some magic items operate as if cast by the lowest-level character that could cast that spell (e.g. cure light wounds scrolls & potions heal 1d8+1 hp)  Does the same principle apply here?  If so can you point me to the relevant rules section?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### The CMB is +3.

From [magic item descriptions](https://www.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?Name=Magic%20Item%20Descriptions&Category=Magic%20Items):

> **Caster Level (CL):** The next item in a notational entry gives the caster level of the item, indicating its relative power. The caster level determines the item’s saving throw bonus, as well as range or other level-dependent aspects of the powers of the item (if variable). It also determines the level that must be contended with should the item come under the effect of a dispel magic spell or similar situation.

Tidewater Cutlass has CL 3rd, so the CMB would be 3 (CL) + 0 (casting modifier) = +3. In most (but not all) cases, the CL for an item will be the minimum required. Hydraulic Push just has a requirement of CL 1, but the Tidewater Cutlass is also a +1 weapon and [that has its own requirement](https://www.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?Name=Creating%20Magic%20Weapons&Category=Magic%20Item%20Creation):

> Creating a magic weapon has a special prerequisite: The creator’s caster level must be at least three times the enhancement bonus of the weapon. If an item has both an enhancement bonus and a special ability, the higher of the two caster level requirements must be met. A magic weapon must have at least a +1 enhancement bonus to have any melee or ranged special weapon abilities.

This gives a minimum CL of 3, which is what the item is made at. The ability score for a general magic item [uses the minimum possible ability score](https://www.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?Name=Saving%20Throws%20Against%20Magic%20Item%20Powers&Category=Magic%20Items):

> For a saving throw against a spell or spell-like effect from a magic item, the DC is 10 + the level of the spell or effect + the ability modifier of the minimum ability score needed to cast that level of spell.

While this is for a DC, the same premise applies. The minimum ability score to cast [Hydraulic Push](https://aonprd.com/SpellDisplay.aspx?ItemName=hydraulic%20push) is 11 which gives a modifier of +0, so the overall CMB is +3.

Comment: The +1 ability modifier is in line with the rules [regarding the DC of Saving Throws from items](https://www.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?Name=Saving%20Throws%20Against%20Magic%20Item%20Powers&Category=Magic%20Items).

Comment: Wouldn't that indicate that there should be a 0 casting modifier because the minimum score for casting a 1st-level spell is 11?

Comment: Ope; thank you Ifusaso for the source and sideromancer for the correction.